# Using convolution in order to derive an image rise wrong results on the edges

Tags: python, convolution, derivative

I'm taking an online course of image processing in which all the problem sets were given in *MATLAB*. Nevertheless, I'm trying to solve them with *Python* and I get some unexpected results when I try to compute image derivative using convolution with the following kernel: `[0.5,0, -0.5]`.

Given row `i`, I want to calculate the columns derivatives using convolution with `g`.

```
image[i,:] = [1,2,3,4]
g = [0.5,0,-0.5]
```

I convolute the two using the following code:

```
    inImage_i_conv = np.zeros_like(inImage_i)

    for j in range(0,len(inImage_i)-1):
        conv = []
        for m in range(len(dy)):
            l = m-1
            conv.append(inImage_i[j-l]*dy[l+1])
        inImage_i_conv[j] = np.sum(conv)
```

and the result is `array([-1,  1,  1,  0])`.
The reason for having `-1` at the beginning is that under `j = 0` and `l = 1`, I actually get the `[-1]` element, which in *Python* is the `n`th element.

Should I add a `0` before the `i`th row (or equivalently `0` column on the leftmost column of the image)? Should I add a copy of the first element to the left?

What is the common practice? because my results are obviously wrong.

Comment: You don't want to use built in functions?

Comment: Well, I'm not doing this in order to get credits but in the PS file it was written to "Write a function that computes the magnitude of an image derivative. You should derive the image in
each direction separately (rows and column) using simple convolution with [1; 0; −1] and [1, 0, −1] to get the two image derivatives. Next, use these derivative images to compute the magnitude image." So I'll keep trying to manually compute them and if I would not succeed I'll go to the built in options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you wish to right the convolution by yourself here is a good start.

```
import numpy as np

def zero_pad(X, pad):
    X_pad = np.pad(X, pad, 'constant', constant_values=0)
    return X_pad

def conv_step(x, W):
        return np.sum(np.multiply(x, W))

def conv(s, k):
    diff = abs(len(s) - len(k) - 1)
    slide = len(k)
    # flip kernel
    k = k [::-1]
    Z = np.zeros(shape=len(s)-diff)
    for i in range(Z.shape[0]):
        Z[i] = conv_step(s[i:i+slide], k)
    return Z

s = [1,2,3,4]
g = [0.5,0,-0.5]
print(np.convolve(s, g, 'same'))  # [ 1.   1.   1.  -1.5]
print(conv(zero_pad(s,1),g))  # [ 1.   1.   1.  -1.5]
```

You can see that it returns the same as the built-in function `np.convolve`.
It follows the basic steps in convolution, which you see in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

1. pad the vector to the desired length
2. flip the kernel (or the input)
3. create a fill-to vector of the desired length
4. iterate over it and each time do the multiplication followed summation